# How to get all products with their variation in random order in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce shop that holds variable products and I want to show all products with their variation products as well as in shop page.
My code is given below:

```
$params = array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'rand');

$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

query_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
));

if (have_posts()) : 
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
echo '<h2>'.the_title.'</h2>';
if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) 
{
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ($available_variations as $key => $value){
        if($value['variation_is_active']==1){
            // varible products details
        }
    }
}
endwhile; 
  the_posts_pagination();
  wp_reset_postdata();
else:
  echo 'No Products';
endif:
```

// I am getting products but only randomise main product not variation

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> To get variable product you have to use `product_variation` in
>   `post_type` key.

So your `$params` and `query_posts` should look like this:

```
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'), // <-- check this line.
    'orderby' =>
    'rand'
);
//...
//...
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'), // <-- check this line.
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
    )
);
```

Reference: [Get List of All WooCommerce Products](http://www.functionsphp.com/get-list-of-all-woocommerce-products/)

Hope this helps!